# How should I write a copy constructor to initialise another object?

Tags: c++, oop, destructor

Say, as a simplified example, I have a class object House which also has an object Kitchen.

Here is the header file:

```
class Kitchen {
   private:
       int width;
       int height;
       int length;
   public:
       Kitchen(int width, height, length); // default constructor
};

class House {
   private:
       int houseId;
       Kitchen newKitchen;
   public:
       House(Kitchen newKitchen, int houseId); // default constructor
       House& operator=(House const& other); // copy assignment
       House(House const& other); // copy constructor
       ~House(); // destructor
};
```

Copying `houseId` works fine within the copy assignment function. But I'm getting an error referring to `House::House(House const& other) { *this = other; }` as the following:

```
error: constructor for 'House' must explicitly initialize the member 'newKitchen' which does not have a default constructor
```

which I'm not sure about as I thought my declaration of a default constructor covered this?

Comment: If everything in your class members is trivially copyiable, the best choice is not to write a copy constructor at all. The compiler generates one by default.

Comment: ... and `Kitchen(int width, height, length);` and `House(Kitchen newKitchen, int houseId);` are not default constructors.

Comment: Side note: It is usually easier to have the assignment operator use the copy constructor rather than the other way around. When you have members or base classes that require initialization, assignment can't cut it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, your "default constructor" in `Kitchen` is *not* a default constructor, it is a user-defined constructor. It should initialize the members, and also I would re-enable copy and move behavior following the [rule of five](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three).

```
class Kitchen {
   private:
       int width;
       int height;
       int length;
   public:
       // Use member initialization list
       Kitchen(int _width, int _height, int _length) : width(_width), height(_height), length(_length) {}

       // Rule of 5
       Kitchen(Kitchen const&) = default;
       Kitchen& operator=(Kitchen const&) = default;
       Kitchen(Kitchen&&) = default;
       Kitchen& operator=(Kitchen&&) = default;
};
```

Then later your `House` can use this user-defined constructor in a similar way

```
House(Kitchen _newKitchen, int _houseId) : houseId(_houseId), newKitchen(_newKitchen) {}
```

Note that your `Kitchen` could simply be a POD aggregate type to save the trouble

```
class Kitchen
{
public:
    int width;
    int height;
    int length;
}
```

This will follow the "rule of zero" and will be default constructable, aggregate initializable, copyable, and moveable. The same would then follow for your `House` class as well.

Comment: Hi, many thanks for your comment. I've tried to implement what you've suggested and I'm still getting the same errors. I've created an initialiser list for House and Kitchen in my user-defined constructors

Comment: @mlan If you've implemented what Cory suggested, you can't get the same error. [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/v76a3d)